# Why was I able to connect with SSH2 to an SFTP server with gFTP?

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp

I'm learning Linux and on Windows when I used Filezilla I would connect using the sftp protocol. I noticed gFTP didn't have the option so I tried SSH2 and set the port to 22 and it worked. Why did this happen and is it safe to keep doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SFTP piggybacks on top of SSH. From the [gFTP FAQ](http://gftp.seul.org/faq.html):

> The SSH2 protocol uses the sftp-server executable on the remote host [...]

This means that as long as you can connect via SSH and have `sftp-server` available on the remote system, gFTP will log in via SSH and invoke the SFTP server on its own when the SSH2 protocol is selected. This is perfectly safe.

Comment: What is a piggyback function?

Comment: @Celeritas: SSH is a transport protocol, SFTP is an application protocol that uses SSH as its transport, much in the same way that XML-RPC uses HTTP.